# Simple chi2 test fails

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

If I use (from `chisq.unif.test {spgs}`)

```
  values <- 0.50, 0.98, 0.89, 0.44, 0.71, 0.73, 0.97, 0.32, 0.90, 1.00, 0.06, 0.18, 0.58, 1.00, 0.77, 0.75, 0.10, 0.07, 0.92, 0.21, 0.49, 0.74, 0.96, 0.77, 0.46, 0.99, 0.86, 0.24, 0.83, 0.86, 0.77, 0.13, 0.59, 0.34, 0.63, 0.44
  chisq.unif.test(values)
```

The following error pops up

```
  chisq.test(counts, ...) : 'x' must at least have 2 elements
```

I try to find out what the problem is but could not. Because the same happens with this vector of numbers:

```
values <- c(0.5633333, 0.8852778, 0.6505556, 0.3330556, 0.5300000, 0.6838889, 0.3561111, 0.8591667, 0.8563889, 0.4791667, 0.1155556, 0.2380556, 0.8822222, 0.9563889, 0.8100000, 0.3775000, 0.2613889, 0.1222222, 0.9322222, 0.2858333, 0.5452778, 0.6991667, 0.7419444, 0.6605556, 0.2144444, 0.9988889, 0.9430556, 0.4911111, 0.4011111, 0.5772222, 0.7347222, 0.3469444, 0.5458333, 0.5494444, 0.8308333, 0.8344444)
```

But if I just generate random numbers with the same length or the same length of unique values, the test works in most cases but sometimes fails. What is wrong with the vectors above?

E.g

```
randValues <- runif(length(values))
randValues <- runif(length(unique(values)))

chisq.unif.test(randValues)
```

Totally do not get it.

Comment: But why bin at all? The chi-square test throws away some of the information here, and binning is arbitrary. We could argue about which test was better, but the only advantage I can imagine for a chi-square test is that it might be familiar already to the researcher or to consumers of the research. (Also, just plot the data and if in doubt compare with some simulations from the reference distribution.)

Comment: Hi Nick, I do not really get your point. What would be your proposed solution to check if these values differ significantly from a uniform distribution? Thanks

Comment: Any number of alternative tests e.g. Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Anderson-Darling. I would rather use graphical methods myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from:

```
?chisq.unif.test
....
min.bin.size: The minimum number of data points to have in each bin.
          If bins cannot be chosen without violating this constraint,
          an error is generated.  The default is 10.  This parameter is
          ignored if ‘bins’ is specified.
```

The test will bin your values and I guess with that above, you hit something less than 10. If you do:

```
chisq.unif.test(values,min.bin.size=8)

    Discrete uniform(0,1) chi-squared test

data:  values
X-squared = 0.058824, df = 1, a = 0, b = 1, p-value = 0.8084

 chisq.unif.test(values,min.bin.size=9)
Error in chisq.test(counts, ...) : 'x' must at least have 2 elements
```

You can also manually define the bins..

Comment: For the record: the software is in error here, not the user.  The applicability of the chi-squared test depends on the *expected* counts in the bins, not on the "number of data points" in each bin.  Moreover, with larger tables the test is quite accurate even when a substantial portion of the bins have expectations less than 10 (even less than 5, a more common threshold).